# Duplicate element name 'PropertyName' Mongodb driver c# exception

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this query which works when I run it in Robo 3T:

```
db.getCollection('groupSchedule').aggregate([{ "$match" : { "GroupId" : ObjectId("598dd346e5549706a80680bf") } }, 
{ "$lookup" : { "from" : "schedule", "localField" : "ScheduleIds", "foreignField" : "_id", "as" : "Schedule" } }, 
{ "$unwind" : "$Schedule" }, 
{ "$match" : {"$or": [{ "Schedule.End.ByDate" : {"$gte":new Date()}},{ "Schedule.End.ByDate" : null}] } }, 
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$GroupId", "SurveyIds" : { "$addToSet" : "$Schedule.SurveyId" }, "ScheduleIds" : { "$addToSet" : "$Schedule._id" } } }, 
{ "$project" : { "_id" : 0, "SurveyIds" : 1, "ScheduleIds": 1 } }])
```

However, when I try to do the same thing using the C# driver as  it blows up saying that:

> "Duplicate element name 'Schedule.End.ByDate'.",

Here's the code:

```
return new List<BsonDocument>
{
    Common.Util.MongoUtils.Match(new BsonDocument { { "GroupId", groupId } }),
    Common.Util.MongoUtils.Lookup(scheduleCollections, "ScheduleIds", "_id", "Schedule"),
    Common.Util.MongoUtils.Unwind("$Schedule"),
    Common.Util.MongoUtils.Match(new BsonDocument
    {
        {
            "$or", new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "Schedule.End.ByDate", BsonNull.Value
                },
                {
                    "Schedule.End.ByDate", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {
                            "$gte", DateTime.UtcNow
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }),
    Group(),
    Common.Util.MongoUtils.Project(new BsonDocument
    {
        { "_id", 0 },
        { "SurveyIds", 1 },
        { "Schedules", 1 }
    })
};
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `BsonDocument` for your `$or` operator, you're effectively trying to create the following:

```
"$or": {
    "Schedule.End.ByDate": null,
    "Schedule.End.ByDate": { "$gte" : ISODate("...") }
}
```

If we look again at your error message:

> "Duplicate element name 'Schedule.End.ByDate'.",

It's clear that you *have* duplicated the `Schedule.End.ByDate` element name, which is invalid and not what was intended.

Instead, you want to use `BsonArray` to wrap two *separate* objects, in order to produce the result you have in your Robo 3T query. To achieve that, you can use the following adaptation of your C# code:

```
"$or", new BsonArray
{
    new BsonDocument
    {
        { "Schedule.End.ByDate", BsonNull.Value }
    },
    new BsonDocument
    {
        {
            "Schedule.End.ByDate", new BsonDocument
            {
                { "$gte", DateTime.UtcNow }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following, which matches your Robo 3T query for the `$or` section:

```
{ "$or" : [
    { "Schedule.End.ByDate" : null },
    { "Schedule.End.ByDate" : { "$gte" : ISODate("...") } }
] }
```